# Python Requests: take all lines from a TXT file, one at a time to get requests from each and save them to a new TXT file

Tags: python, python-requests

This code here gets a bunch of URLS from web archive.org and save them to a new TXT file. I want instead of INPUT (write one url address), to load a bunch of URLS from a TXT file. So  `x=input('URL:')` must be replaced with some code to load each line at a time from a txt file.

I've been trying for few days now, i'm stuck! Please help!

The code:

```
x=input('Enter your url:-')
r = requests.get('http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey'.format(x))
with open('url.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n')
    f.writelines(str(r.text))
    f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read URLs from file you can use next example:

```py
import requests

urls = []
with open("something.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        urls.append(line)

archive_url = "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey"

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
        print(r.text, file=f_out)
        print("\n", file=f_out)
```

---

`something.txt` contains domains, for example:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
```

`output.txt` contains response from `requests`

Comment: It takes only the last word; "yahoo.com"

Comment: @user19033073 It reads `urls.txt` line-by-line and appends the domains to list `urls`. Then iterates over the list and makes request to each url in this list.

Comment: It has to be "something.txt" because in my example "urls.txt" must be the new file. Maybe some confusion here ?

Comment: @user19033073 Then rename `urls.txt` in my example to `something.txt` and put the domains there.

Comment: One more thing, i had the code: "if 'word' in line:"  to write to txt only if specify word exist in the line, but i can't add now, i doesnt seem to work anymore....

Comment: Can you HELP me Please ?!

Comment: @user19033073 I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124193/python-trying-to-write-to-txt-only-lines-that-contains-specific-word-instead

Comment: any thoughts on this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584182/load-lines-from-external-file-as-python-code

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have all URLs in urls.txt file each separated by new lines and then open it with the readlines() function. it will return the list of all URLs. here is the complete code.

```
import requests
with open('urls.txt') as file:
    # get the list of urls
    urls_list=file.readlines()
    for x in urls_list:
        r = requests.get('http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey'.format(x))
        print(r.status_code)
```