# Python: Trying to write to .txt only lines that contains specific word, instead of the whole text

Tags: python, python-requests

This Python code here reads list.txt which contains websites links and then extract URLS from webarchive.org from those websites, and writes them to urls.txt. What I want is to extract ONLY lines that contains specific "WORD". As I see, my code extract all lines if a specific "WORD" exist in one line.

Can anyone explain why? Thank you in advance!

The code:

```
urls = []
with open("list.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        urls.append(line)

archive_url = "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey"

with open("url.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:

        r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
        if 'WORD' in archive_url:
            print(r.text, file=f_out)
            print("\n", file=f_out)
```

I tried to replace `if 'WORD' in archive_url:` with `if 'WORD' in url:` but it doesn't write anything to TXT!
I don't know how to print only the LINE which contain "WORD"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests

urls = []
with open("list.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        urls.append(line)

archive_url = "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey"

with open("url.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
        for line in r.text.splitlines():
            if "your_word" in line:
                print(line, file=f_out)
        print("\n", file=f_out)
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173552/python-trying-to-exclude-nearly-duplicate-lines-from-writing-to-file-txt

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("url.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:
        if 'WORD' in url:
            r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
            f_out.write(r,'\n')
```

Comment: it doesn't write anything to txt :(

Comment: it simply starts and then ends without any error, and nothing writen to url.txt

Comment: if it didn't write anything it means "WORD" in not in url

Comment: You want to write all urls that are in archive_url or what? I can help you with that.

Comment: I have replaced "word" with words that exists, but nothing...

Comment: If i replace url with archive_url it writes to txt, but it writes all links, with and without "word" in it....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Yes, i know. But here are about 2-3 lines of code that are wrong or are in incorect position. I'm just trying to understand where is the problem with the code. I have edited the post now.