# Load lines from external file as Python code

Tags: python

I have code that has multiple IF conditions in it. I would like to load these IF conditions from a text or Python file, to work more clean.

The code:

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
    for line in r.text.splitlines():
            if THIS:
              DO that
            if THIS:
              DO that
            if THIS:
              DO that

             ..etc..
```

I would like to do this instead:

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
    for line in r.text.splitlines():

             -- LOAD 'IF' CONDITIONS FROM FILE --
```

Comment: You could import a function containing the conditions from a separate python file. Is that the sort of thing you are after? So in your main python file it would just look like a single function call.

Comment: I have tryed. It doesn't recognize "r" if "r" is in IF condition. If i move there "r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))" then it goes further, doesn't recognize another one, and so on i move all code there...

Comment: You would have to pass everything the function needs in as arguments. Eg `def check_request(r)...`. Then the function returns everything you need from it in the `return` statement. Maybe if you show what you tried we can help you debug.

Comment: Does passing r as an argument to the function not solve this?